# Replace string element with split method

Tags: python

I need to change the number in a string like "Higher id: 38".

I can get "38" with `string.split(" ")[2]`, do you know if there is a simple way to change this value? 
I tried `comment.split(" ")[2] = "55"` but it didn't worked.

Am I constrained to do the modification by running manually through the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable, thus you can not modify the string in place. You have to make a new one:

```
>>> mystr = "Higher id: 38"
>>> mylist = mystr.split(' ')
>>> mylist[-1] = "55" # t[-1] accesses the last element in the list
>>> print ' '.join(mylist)
Higher id: 55
```

If you are confident that 38 will only occur once in the string, you can use `replace()`. Just remember that it returns the replaced string, and does not actually replace the string in place:

```
>>> mystr = "Higher id: 38"
>>> mynewstr = mystr.replace('38', '55')
>>> print mynewstr
Higher id: 55
```

Or even regex can be used:

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.sub(r'(\d.*?)$', '55', mystr)
Higher id: 55
```

Comment: It can be any number so your first solution is the one I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> "Higher id: 38".replace('38', '55')
'Higher id: 55'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Haidro's is what I needed.